# Posted a bounty, now my reputation is too low to comment on the bounty question

Tags: bug, comments, bounties

My reputation was 89, then I posted a 50pt bounty on a question.  Now with a reputation of 39, I cannot comment on that same question.

I believe further comments may help anyone trying to answer that question. Shouldn't I at least be able to comment on my open bounties?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Easy fix, ask an appropriate question instead of commenting.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually now that I actually think about it I agree.  Suggested edits should be sufficient for bounty situations.  If it's not easily explained by an approvable suggested edit it probably shouldn't have been a bounty in the first place.

Comment: In this instance, I wanted to add further detail on the circumstances that led to the issue for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369177/code-contract-rewrite-failing-with-could-not-resolve-member-reference

Comment: Workaround: Answer questions until my reputation goes back up!

Comment: It would appear you can comment again. :)

Answer (score 14):

Well, suspecting you've put that bounty not on a question of your own (you can always put comments at posts regarding your own questions and answers), seems you've reached *catch 22* now.

It's not a bug, the features are addressing orthogonal issues.

- You give away rep for a bounty (probably unwisely)
- You need certain rep to comment on posts that don't involve you

If that question didn't get an answer that satisfies you, and you really didn't find an answer for your concerns, the proper action might have been writing your own question (mentioning your research and all that), rather than putting a bounty.

---

Alternative solution (plain straight forward), comment **before** putting the bounty.

Comment: Commenting before the bounty don't attract the required attention, which is the main goal of the bounties on others questions.